# Counting the sum of a list in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where column "lists" has lists:

```
l = ({'lists' : [[2,4,6],[8,10,12],[14,16,18]]})

df = pd.DataFrame(data = l)
```

I' trying to add a new column that is the sum of the elements in these lists:

```
    lists           sum
0   [2, 4, 6]       12
1   [8, 10, 12]     30
2   [14, 16, 18]    48
```

So far I've tried:

```
df['sum'] = [sum(a) for a in zip(*df['lists'])]
```

but this sums the elements from all lists for example on row 0 the sum would be 2+8+14=24

How can I change the code to sum the elements inside one list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `sum` in [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df['sum'] = df['lists'].apply(sum)
```

Or list comprehension without `zip`:

```
df['sum'] = [sum(a) for a in df['lists']]
```

---

```
print (df)
          lists  sum
0     [2, 4, 6]   12
1   [8, 10, 12]   30
2  [14, 16, 18]   48
```